# Stoping code by pressing button on tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I'm currently trying to create a alarm system using two Raspberry Pi's, the trigger to let the alarm go of is simulated by a button (by breadboard) connected to one of the pi's. When this button is pressed (so the alarm gets activated) the user has 30 seconds the time to turn of the alarm by pressing a button in a GUI made with tkinter. If the button is not pressed within 30 seconds there wil be sent a TCP to a different RPI.

So now the question: how do I create a GUI with tkinter that stops the pi from sending a TCP if the user presses the button 'STOP ALARM' on the GUI.

This is what I tried:

(I did not include the buttonpressed & sendtcp functions because they're very long.)

```
import import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from tkinter import *
import socket
import sys
import time
def alarmstopped()
    return True
count = 0
while True:
    if buttonPressed() == True: #Button pressed
        while True:
            if alarmStoped() == True: #Stops 30sec count
                break
                count = 0
            elif count >=30:
                sendTCP() #Sends TCP to other RPI
                time.sleep(0.2)
                break
            else:
                count += 1
                time.sleep(1)
                print(count)
                continue
    else:
        continue
root = Tk()
button = Button(master=root, cursor='hand2', text='stop alarm', command=alarmStoped)
button.pack()
```

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/3AMY5Kdx)

Hope you guys can help me and feel free to correct my English if I made mistakes ;)

Comment: Can you clarify the portion you need help with? Do you already have a button that enables the alarm? Also, you almost definitely do not need a function for `buttonPressed`, the built-in command argument for Tkinter buttons can take care of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not want the while loop at all. Instead, to start the alarm use `after`, and to stop it use `after_cancel`. `after` will schedule a function to be run in the future (eg: to turn the alarm on), and `after_cancel` will stop that job from running.

Here's a simple example illustrating the technique by setting the alarm in 10 seconds:

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_start_alarm():
    global alarm_id
    alarm_id = root.after(10000, start_alarm)
    alarm.configure(text="Alarm starting soon...")

def on_stop_alarm():
    global alarm_id
    alarm.configure(text="")
    root.after_cancel(alarm_id)

def start_alarm():
    alarm.configure(text='Alarm! Alarm!', foreground="red")

root = tk.Tk()

alarm = tk.Label(root, text="", width=20)
start = tk.Button(root, text="Start", command=on_start_alarm)
stop = tk.Button(root, text="Stop", command=on_stop_alarm)

alarm.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
start.pack(side="top")
stop.pack(side="top")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you know how I can start the alarm by pressing a button that is connected to my Pi using a breadboard. [This is how in connect the button into python](https://pastebin.com/TjZi6WRw)

Comment: @Tymo: I don't know anything about raspberry pi. Assuming you do it by calling a python function, call that function from `start_alarm`. You can put any code you want in there.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I created an extra function to get the input fromt the button on the Pi, its working even better then I expected. Thanks!